# How can I prevent Thunderbird/AVG virus detection prompts

Tags: anti-virus, thunderbird, avg-antivirus

I have just got back from holiday and have over 1000 emails sitting in my various mail boxes, but every few emails contains a virus (nothing unusual there). Now whilst Thunderbird and AVG do a great job to protect me from them, I have to click at least 2 (sometimes 3) dialogues each time one is found and then reselect Get Mail.

Is there any way to disable this prompts so that I can actually get my email downloaded, I am happy to trust the software and have it remove all potential rogue emails

Comment: I'd go with Avast mail scanner. Who wants to trade a license? Got IS but I don't use the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about turning off AVG Email Scanner? It doesn't work?

Comment: I had to turn off the resident shield too it seems, it was this that was blocking it not the actual email scanner